# Button and search field to search url in html

Tags: html, button

I need to write in html a field where a user will enter a url and a search button to search for the url that the user has entered

tenks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script>

function loadSite(){
    var site = document.getElementById("bar").value;
    window.location = site;
}

</script>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="bar">
    <button onclick=loadSite()>GO</button>

</body>
```

Comment: so you have the code, but where is your problem/question?